# Django Celery socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu, celery, django-celery

When running the command `celery status` on my production server I get this error:

But, Celery works and the worker do run, what is this error and why can I not run this command?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-32-9-39:/srv/project/logs/celery$ celery status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.0.11', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 946, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 890, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 179, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 882, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 857, in execute
    return cls(app=self.app).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 142, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 112, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 652, in run
    .run('ping', **dict(kwargs, quiet=True, show_body=False))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 505, in run
    return self.do_call_method(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 527, in do_call_method
    replies = handler(method, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 570, in call
    return getattr(i, method)(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 79, in ping
    return self._request('ping')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 54, in _request
    timeout=self.timeout, reply=True))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 260, in broadcast
    channel=channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 235, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 748, in default_channel
    self.connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 733, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 692, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 109, in establish_connection
    heartbeat=conninfo.heartbeat)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.transport = create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 250, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Settings...

```
CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/srv/project/"

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
CELERYCTL="$CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/srv/project/logs/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/srv/project/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="ubuntu"
CELERYD_GROUP="ubuntu"

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings"
```

Comment: Could you post some configuration, please?

Comment: updated see question :)

Comment: which broker have you chosen?

Comment: Okay, so have you checked that it's up and running? The celery client can well be up and running with its workers but the broker might be down or not started. That's what the error says anyways, could also be that you're supplying the wrong credentials.

Comment: yep its up and running because I can see tasks in SQS and they all get successfully completed. that's what confusing me just this and a few other commands don't work.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750531/celery-import-and-sqs-connection-issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Launch from manage.py shell...

```
sudo python manage.py celery status
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: @chachan sudo is just for elevated privileges. If you don't need it then you are doing something right!

Comment: Its still giving `[Errno 111]  Connection refused`

Comment: @cold_coder It's a connection refused message so check you have the correct IP, username or password.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had to add the following lines at the `__init__.py` file at the package containing `settings.py` and `celery.py` files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Check http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html for reference.